# Where should I ask a question about Android programming best practices?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am not sure where should I ask my question. I want to ask where should I program a UDP packet sending (Directly from an Activity, or maybe in a background Service).

Comment: There are plentty of tags at Stack Overflow you can already use to narrow your question context.

Comment: "Best is to use X - it's quickest".  "No!  Use Y, it uses less memory".  "No! Use Z it uses less CPU". "No! Use A, it uses fewer cores".  "No! Use B - it's easy to use".   "No! Use C - it's easier to debug".  "No! Use D - it's open source".  "No! Use E - it's well-supported"...........................................

Comment: [Highly related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/1228)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest site I could find where asking about best practices would be OK is [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> ## Best practices in general
>
> It's OK to ask "Does this code follow common best practices?", **but not
>   "What is the best practice regarding X?"*** Questions should not contain
>   purely generic, hypothetical code, such as
>
> ```
> if condition_a:
> do_something() else if condition_b:
> do_something_else() else:
> do_something_even_different()
> ```
>
> Also watch out for hypothetical wording, such as "Imagine" or "Let's
>   say we have…"

*emphasis added

So you can ask about it there as long as it's still in the context of having people review your existing code.

**NOTE**: I am not a user over at Code Review, I'm going entirely based on what's in their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/). I'd recommend looking for discussions about best practices over on their [meta site](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/) and looking at existing best practice questions before posting a question (which should contain real code for review).

I imagine someone who is active there will chime in with "yes, that's accurate" or "actually we hate these kinds of questions".

Answer (score 6):

Questions on "Best Practices" are, by definition, primarily opinion based (not entirely, but *primarily*).

As such they are not a good fit on Stack Overflow. For more information see the [help regarding on-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow *might* be a good place to ask such a question, as long as you make sure it's not:

- primarily opinion based; e.g. "what is the best way to send UDP packets"; or
- very broad, such as "how can I send UDP packets?"

It looks like the question you want to ask falls in this category, so that would be **not** be considered on-topic and is likely to get closed quickly. Also see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

---

Questions that *would* be on-topic would include:

- "I've tried sending UDP packets using an Activity and I've run into this problem!" Be sure to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!
- "What are the reasons to use a background Service over just programming in an Activity?"; this is a bit of a more general question, but there's a good chance it'll help you solve your problem. It would be a good idea to add some context as to what *exactly* you're confused about and want to know, because chances are that a generic "what are background Services for?" question is answered in the first paragraph of the official documentation.
- "Are there any functional differences between sending UDP packets in an Activity and background service?" – I know very little about Android, so I'm not sure how much sense this question makes, but if it makes sense you're going to need to be *very* careful in the phrasing when asking questions such as this, since can easily come off as the broad "what is the best way do do it?"-type of question. It's probably best to provide an MCVE for both cases. Make sure you focus on real technical differences, and not an opinionated "what is best?"

Also see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You can try asking on meta (as you've did) or the [Android chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android) if you're not sure if a question would be considered on-topic and want some help from other users determining how to best ask a question.

Note that Android is a popular tag and chances are that all of the above questions have already been asked, so be sure to **search**!